# Java and NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial: project fails to run on Snapshot 8

Tags: java, glassfish, netbeans-8

I am studying Java through the [NetBeans E-commerce tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html). It's a bit out of date, but I've been able to work around the deprecations while using NetBeans IDE v8.1 and Glassfish 4.1.1 (the tutorial uses NetBeans 6/7 and Glassfish 3.x.x).

However, on Step 9, "Integrating Business Transaction Logic", my build suddenly started failing after the sub-section Setting up the Transaction Programmatically. Both my own work and the [official SnapShot 8](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples%252FJavaEE%252Fecommerce%252FAffableBean_snapshot8.zip) throw the same error.

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not set session.CategoryFacade field 
controller.ControllerServlet.categoryFacade to controller.ControllerServlet
```

I've examined all the files referred to in this error, but I'm not finding any syntax errors or anything else obviously wrong.

Can anyone explain what this error means and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same issue but after restarting the GlassFish Server and selecting "Clean and Build" option for my project, the error was resolved.

Hope it helps!